# Performance improvement for web services

Tags: performance, web-services, ibm-sterling

We have a webservice, which will be called to provide the delivery date of the product, while purchasing in eComm website.

We are using IBM Sterling Order Management in the backend, and its OOB webservice and its OOB service.

This webservice (WSDL) is taking more time, more than 40 seconds, which create timeoutexception in other integrated systems (Middleware).

So we want to improve the performance of this webservice. Could you please help me to provide the way to improve the performance ? Will it be improved if the Server's spec has been upgraded ? As it the OOB service, we can't customize it.

Comment: Are you dealing with big/huge XML document? Could that be source of the issue?

Comment: No its not a big xml, but the back end process takes more time to get the delivery date.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to figure out the performance bottleneck. To start with you could put a verbose trace on the OOB Webservice. Use the logs and see if you can zero-in on any particular component or sql taking consuming majority of the time. If it's sql, you can tune/baseline the OOB query/tables using indexes.
If you have any user exits implemented (for the OOB API), ensure that they are lean and aren't making any expensive API calls like changeOrder API.

Answer (score 0):

One of the questions to be asked here would be if the webservice needs to respond with the actual processing results or if it could move the actual processing to the background eg: separate integration server and just respond with a simple acknowledgement of the webservice request. If the service only needs to respond with an acknowledgement you could possibly move the actual processing to a separate async service.

Answer (score 0):

First try to find out where the actual problem is and hence here the few pointers,
1) Check in OMS how much time the service is taking with the same input which you are using ti invoke the webservice.
2) If from OMS end response time is fine then check the network latency/bandwidth.
3) CPU usage while hitting the webservice.